# Is it any meaningful taking the histogram of many histograms?

Tags: machine-learning, histogram, exploratory-data-analysis

So I’m working on pixel-level assessment of chest x-ray images from the NIH Chest X-ray dataset. The diseases labels on the images are a set of *z* different categories (i.e. Pneumonia, effusion, etc…). I’ve already been analyzing the histograms of images per each category, but then I wanted to go through all the histograms per disease class and average it into one histogram, producing a histogram of histograms for each of the disease class set, ending up with *z* collective histograms. Does this make any sense statistically, I wanted to get Image analysis SMEs’ opinions on this approach.
Have anyone did that before? Any pitfalls I should be careful with?

Below is the code I used:

````
figure, m_axis = plt.subplots(int((len(all_labels)+1)/2), 2, 
                              figsize= (10, 15),
                              sharex=True,
                              sharey=True,
                              constrained_layout=True)
if len(all_labels)%2!=0:
    figure.delaxes(m_axis[int((len(all_labels)+1)/2)-1][1])
    
bins = np.arange(-0.5, 255+1, 1)
idx = img_ind = axis_ind = fig_ind = 0

# Building the histogram data dictionary
categories_histograms = {}
for idx, c_label in enumerate(all_labels):
    imgs = sample_df[sample_df['Finding Labels'] == c_label]['path']
    imgs_count=len(imgs)
    #print(io.imread(imgs.iloc[0]).ravel().shape)
    hist_accumulator = np.zeros_like(exposure.histogram(img_as_float(
                                                io.imread(imgs.iloc[0])), 
                                                nbins=256)[0])

    
    for img in imgs:
        img_io = io.imread(img)
        img_hist = exposure.histogram(img_as_float(img_io), nbins=256)

        hist_accumulator = np.add(hist_accumulator, img_hist[0])

        
        img_ind = img_ind+1
        print("\r{}: Image {} of {}{:>20}".format(c_label, img_ind, imgs_count,'\r'), 
              end='', flush=True)
        

    # Normalization of compund histogram
    hist_norm = hist_accumulator / imgs_count
    # Building the histogram dictionary for the categories
    categories_histograms[c_label] = hist_norm
    img_ind, axis_ind = 0, idx%2
    if idx > 1:
        fig_ind = fig_ind+(idx+1)%2

    m_axis[fig_ind, axis_ind].plot(hist_norm)
    m_axis[fig_ind, axis_ind].set_title(c_label)

```
````

Comment: "Makes sense" for what purpose?  "Statistically" doesn't give us any information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Would a combined histogram of all the chest x-ray pictures per disease class give any more information more than the individual picture assessment?

Comment: Would you use these combined histograms for visual inspection or for further processing?

Comment: @dariober yes, and that is a question I myself is exploring, should I? I’m training a VGG16 network

Comment: "Yes" to which one? Visual inspection or processing? For processing (but to some extent also for visual inspection), it's usually better to avoid averaging or otherwise combining data points since you lose information about the sample to sample variability. (P.S.: I know nothing about image analysis!)

Comment: @dariober that confirms my doubts, absolutely you are right and variance is hence lost. Thank you!